# "Make/do/take/run/keep/give a laugh" — which one makes sense?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

My daughter's teacher (a Canadian in Italy) gave the class an exercise.  They had to choose among *make*, *do*, *take*, *run*, *keep* and *give*, and insert the correct response in front of "a laugh".  We are American and we were mystified.  Is here a correct choice?

Comment: In google Ngrams, "make a laugh" is the clear winner, but in the time frame 1820-1900.

Comment: The 'correct' choice would appear to be [None of the above](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/None_of_the_above)

Answer (score 3):

I believe they're looking for **give a laugh**.

Though I wouldn't use that phrase by itself, I've frequently seen usages like "he gave a hearty laugh."

Comment: I should add that the exercise itself might be flawed. I've taught English abroad and often saw (and still see) mistakes in the textbooks themselves, as they're written by non-native speakers.

Comment: I agree. I think "give a laugh" is literary, rather than vernacular.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the two previous posters that only ‘give’ comes close.

One the teacher might have inclued is ‘have’, as in

> You’re ‘avin’ a larf, incha?

Comment: Very British but thank you...I had a laugh when I read it.

Answer (score 2):

Something hilarious might ['give' you a laugh](http://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy&hl=en&biw=1028&bih=615&noj=1&source=hp&q=he%20gave%20me%20a%20laugh&oq=he%20gave%20me%20a%20laugh&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1358935l1361849l0l1362561l18l9l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0).